# Can't Resize Image to Make Responsive

Tags: html, css

I have a website which uses an eccommerce script to list products. Most of the site seems to be mobile responsive, apart from the product images which stay fixed at a height of 500px. I've been trying to make them responsive but seem to have tried loads of methods and none of them work. The image always stays the same size when viewing on mobiles.

Here is the html code which generates each product image on the product page:

```html
<div class="file_image">
 <div class="t"><div class="b"><div class="l"><div class="r"><div class="bl"><div class="br"><div class="tl"><div class="tr">
  {IMAGE}
 </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
<div class="file_links">
```

And here is the section in the .css stylesheet which controls this div tag:

```css
.file_image
{
float:left;
margin-right:30px;
width:480px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Is there something else I need to add somewhere to make this image responsive? I've tried several things but they don't seem to work. If anyone can help me out here, that would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: Could you provide your live link of web? It would be more convenient to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this,

```
.file_image img
{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and it works! Thank you so much, I wouldn't have thought to try this method! :) Working perfectly now thanks :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

you should try to set your image width in `max-width` instead of `width` for this case.

```
.file_image {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 480px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Hope it might help.
Good Luck'

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just tried it, but it didn't seem to make any difference still?